# Kiel traduki "sign language" respekteme?

Tags: translation, language

Mi aŭdis hodiaŭ, ke surduloj preferas la terminon *signallingvo*, ĉar ili konsideras *signolingvo* insulta en Esperanto. Aliaj diras, ke *gestlingvo* estas insulta. Mi simple neniam aŭdis *signallingvo* en Esperanto antaŭe. Kiel oni ĝuste kaj respekteme traduku "sign language" al Esperanto?

Answer (score 17):

Saluton! Mi estas *usona* surda esperantisto!

La vorto "usona" estas tre grava kaŭze de la surda historio de la usono. La surduloj ĉi tie ne ŝatas multe la vorton "gesture/gesto". Por jaroj estis personoj kiuj ne kredis ke la usona signolingvo estis vere lingvo. Ili pensis ke estis gestaro- a collection of gestures, laŭ l'angla, kaj estis klopodo al komuniki, barbara kaj trista.

Do, mi ne uzus "gestlingvo", sed mi uzus "signolingvo" senprobleme. Sed, ĉu mi sentas ofendita se oni uzas "gestlingvo"? Ne.

Comment: Bonvenon al la Esperanto Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 9):

Kie vi aŭdis tion? Mi neniam aŭdis aŭ legis la vorton "signallingvo". En ekz. la Angla lingvo surduloj forte preferas "sign language", kio estas laŭvorte "signolingvo" en Esperanto, neniel "signallingvo". Simile statas en Svedujo, kie oni nepre uzu "teckenspråk" (laŭvorte "signolingvo").

Mi neniam renkontis la ideon, ke "signolingvo" estas insulta en Esperanto.

Comment: Mi aŭdis ĝin en ĉi tiu filmeto de Evildea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k75RiXGBAQQ (3:25)

Comment: Efektive li diras tion. Kurioze, strange, mistere.

Comment: @ChuckSmith Nu, li diras nur "aŭ signallingvon, mi devas diri", sen ajna klarigo pri tio, *kial* li devas tion diri.

Answer (score 6):

Serĉo en la [Tekstaro de Esperanto](http://tekstaro.com)  kaj la [Esperanta *corpuseye*](http://corp.hum.sdu.dk/cqp.eo.html) montras, ke la plej kutimaj esprimoj por tio estas "gestolingvo" kaj "signolingvo" (simile kutimaj), dum "signallingvo" estas praktike tute neuzata (estas neniu trafo por "signallingvo" en la Tekstaro de Esperanto kaj nur unu en *corpuseye*, kiu tamen tute ne rilatas al surdula lingvo, sed al pergesta balbutado uzata por komuniki kun alilingvano).

Laŭ mi la opinio, ke "gestolingvo" estas ofenda, baziĝas sur anglalingva influo en la kompreno de la vorto, kaj ne el ĝia propre Esperanta signifo. En la angla oni konsideras ofenda la uzon de "gesture" rilate al la gestoj en gestolingvo, ĉar por tio ekzistas pli preciza esprimo "sign". Tamen en Esperanto, "signo" tute ne estas pli preciza ol "gesto", sed fakte pli malpreciza: Ĉio ajn perceptebla, kio konvencie elvokas certan ideon, estas signo. (Fakte ankaŭ en la angla "sign" plej ofte havas tiun pli ĝeneralan signifon; sed ĝi krome konvencie (kaj sufiĉe arbitre kaj konfuzo-kree) havas ankaŭ pli specifan signifon, nome 'vorto de gestolingvo').

Se oni pretas facilanime transpreni nacilingvan komprenon pri ofendeco de iu esprimo al Esperanto, ne ekzistas kialo por limiĝi al la angla. Se oni baziĝas ekzemple sur la germana, oni devas konkludi, ke "signolingvo" estas ofenda, ĉar la forme simila germana "Zeichensprache" estas konsiderata ofenda esprimo por gestolingvo ("Zeichen" estas la germana vorto por "signo"). La germana vorto por gestolingvo estas "Gebärdensprache". "Gebärde" estas vorto, kies sola signifo estas 'vorto de gestolingvo'. Bedaŭrinde nek la angla nek Esperanto havas vorton, kiu havas nur tiun signifon. Sed dum en la angla la sola ne-ofenda elturniĝo estas la uzo de la pli ĝenerala "sign" en pli specifa signifo, en Esperanto ankaŭ la uzo de la jam pli specifa "gesto" en ankoraŭ pli specifa signifo 'vorto de gestolingvo' estas konsiderata ne-ofenda.

La fakto, ke tiu vorto en Esperanto ne estas ofenda, montriĝas interalie per tio, ke ĝin [uzas](http://www.libe.slikom.info/Esperanta%20ligilo/2013/0113.htm) la Ligo Internacia de Blindaj Esperantistoj, kiu certe atentas pri ne-ofenda lingvaĵo rilate al handikapaj malplimultoj.

Mi persone emas kompreni "signolingvo" kiel la germanan "Zeichensprache". Ĉar ĉiu lingvo konsistas el vortoj, laŭvorte "signolingvo" devus simple esti pleonasma esprimo por "lingvo". Sed en tiaj laŭvorte pleonasmaj kunmetaĵoj oni emas doni pli specifan signifon al la preciziga antaŭ-elemento. Ĝuste tiel faras la germana en "Zeichensprache": Ĉar oni kutime ne nomas vortojn "signoj" (oni ja havas la apartan vorton "vorto" por ili), oni ofte emas kompreni "signo"/"Zeichen" en la senco de "nevorta signo", kaj sekve "signolingvo"/"Zeichensprache" estas ajna komunikilo konsistanta el nevortaj signoj (ekzemple la matematika formul-lingvo, la trafika signaro aŭ la nelingva gestaro uzata de subakvaj naĝantoj). Ĉi tiu kompreno de "signolingvo" analoga al la germana "Zeichensprache" laŭ mi pli koheras kun la interna logiko de Esperanto ol la kompreno analoga al la angla "sign language". Kaj laŭ ĉi tiu kompreno, "signolingvo" estas ofenda esprimo por gestolingvo.

"Signallingvo" estas eĉ malpli taŭga esprimo por tio ol "signolingvo". Ekzemploj de signaloj estas ekzemple averta sonsignalo, kiu signalas, ke oni forlasu konstruaĵon pro ebla brulo, aŭ flagosignaloj uzataj surmare por signali ion al aliaj ŝipoj. Signaloj tute ne estas vortoj. Do nomi gestolingvon "signallingvo" ŝajnas al mi la plej ofenda maniero esprimi sin (kaj krome ĝi verŝajne estas apenaŭ komprenata, ĉar praktike neniu uzas "signallingvo" por gestolingvo).

Konklude, mi rekomendas uzi "gestolingvo", kiu laŭ kompreno propra al Esperanto fakte estas malpli ofenda ol "signolingvo" kaj multe malpli ofenda ol "signallingvo".

Answer (score 5):

Mi uzas la terminon "signolingvo", kaj ne "gestlingvo".  "Gesto" estas ĝenerala korpa movo sen preciza signifo, dum "signo" estas semantike preciza parto de lingvo, kiu egalas al "vorto" en parola lingvo.  Mi neniam aŭdis aŭ vidis la formon "signalingvo", kaj mi apenaŭ povas imagi ke iu Surdulo vere komentus tiel pri formo en Esperanto.  "

Oni povus paroli pri "signa lingvo", mi supozas, sed "signolingvo" estas pli preciza.

Comment: Mi skribis "signallingvo" (kun duobla L), ne "signalingvo".

Comment: Ekzistas [Gestuno](https://eo.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestuno) - internacia planita signolingvo. Do mi pensas ke la termino "gestlinvo" povas signifi signolingvon.

Comment: En Esperanto "gesto" ankaŭ povas signifi 'vorto de gestolingvo'. Laŭ mi via kompreno de "gesto" baziĝas sur anglalingva influo. Legu mian respondon por pli preciza klarigo.

Answer (score 3):

Mi lernis (de blindulo) ke la ĝusta vorto estas gestolingvo, sed eble pro nacilingva influo mi ofte (mis-?)diras "signolingvo".

Nek mi iam aŭdis ajna opinio pri malrespektemo enbakita en tiuj esprimoj.

Answer (score 3):

Jen kial mi diras, "Signallingvon". Du apartaj esperantistoj, kiuj ankaŭ estas interpretistoj de la signallingvo konsilis al mi, ke "gestolingvo" kaj "signolingvo" povas esti ofendemaj al surduloj ĉar ĝi ne estas lingvo el "gestoj" kaj "signoj".

Answer (score 1):

Persone, mi diras "gestolingvo" pro diversaj kaŭzoj. Sed, se oni serĉas la opinion de surdaj Esperantistoj, kial demandi tie ĉi?

Answer (score -1):

'Signolingvo' tradukas kiel 'sign language' laŭ [glosbe](https://www.glosbe.com/eo/en/signolingvo) do mi tendencus uzi 'signolingvo' sed mi neniam aŭdis pri signallingvo.